# Symfony 2.3 + FOSComment: Constraints\MinLength not found in AbstractLoader

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I use Symfony 2.3.9 and foscommentbundle 1.*.

While creating a foscomment I have this error.

**Here the error**:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength' not found in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/Loader/AbstractLoader.php line 64
```

Any help please?

Sam

Answer (score 0):

`MinLength` constraint was remove in Symfony 2.3, `Length replace` it 
see http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/constraints/Length.html

You have to use the v2 of foscommentbundle. For example `2.0.*@dev`

Hope it's helpful

Best regard

Comment: The v2 of fos comment bundle has contraint concerning the symfony framework:  Problem 1
    - friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle v2.0.5 requires sensio/framework-extra-bundle >=2.1,<2.3-dev -> no matching package found.

Comment: Your composer.json seem not up to date, please follow that https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json#L9-L22